# Theming form with template file

Tags: theming, forms

I am trying to follow these tutorials (http://themery.com/dgd7/advanced-theming/forms/with-templates and https://www.drupal.org/node/1419390).

And I have created these files:

login_form.module

```
<?php

  function login_theme()
 {
    return array(
      'login_form' => array(
        'render element' => 'form',
        'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'login'),
        'template' => 'login-form',
      )
    );
  }

  function login_menu()
  {
    $items = array();

    $items['cms/login'] = array(
      'title' => 'CMS Login',
      'description' => 'Interface untuk login CMS',
      'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form',
      'page arguments' => array('login_form'),
      'access callback' => TRUE

      //'access arguments' => array('access content')
      //'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
      //'access callback' => 'login_form_access'


    );

    return $items;
  }

  function login_help($path, $arg)
  {
    switch($path)
    {
      case "admin/help#login":
        return "Modul untuk menampilkan interface login CMS.";
        break;
    }
  }

  function login_form($form, &$form_state)
  {
    $form['username'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => 'Username',
      '#required' => TRUE
    );

    $form['password'] = array(
      '#type' => 'password',
      '#title' => 'Password',
      '#required' => TRUE
    );

    $form['submit_button'] = array(
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => 'Login'
    );

    return $form;
  }

  function login_form_validate($form, &$form_state)
  {
  }

  function login_form_submit($form, &$form_state)
  {
    $pesan = '';

    try
    {

      $hasil = db_query(
        "select * from sys_userlis 
        where 
        username = :username AND
        password = :password
        ",
        array(
          ':username' => $form_state['values']['username'],
          ':password' => sha1($form_state['values']['password'])
        )
      );

      if($hasil->rowCount() > 0)
      {

        while($baris = $hasil->fetchAssoc())
        {

          $pesan = 'Berhasil login';
        }
      }
      else
      {
        $pesan = "Hasil query kosong";
      }

    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
      $pesan = "Exception $e";
    }

    drupal_set_message($pesan);
  }
```

and an empty template file: login-form.tpl.php

Both files are in the same directory: /sites/all/modules/login

So my code is a combination of two tutorials.
I want to make a login form and theme it with a template file.

With this code I got a page with 2 entry fields (username and password) and a submit button. While in fact the template file is empty.

What am I missing here?

Thank you.